# Font awesome's light version not available through CDN link

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use any variation of font awesome's icons. I'd like to be able to use the classes .fa .far .fal and so on.

I'm using a CDN for the style sheet found here https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css.
But for some reason not all of the icons are available.
Please help.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a right question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is a free CDN that does not include pro icons. Light versions are pro icons. I would look up the proper way to use a pro CDN, but the website appears to be down for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why, I need a pro licence to have access to all versions of the icons.